# Bad Characters when parsing GML in Java

Tags: java, xml, schema, gml

I'm using the org.w3c.dom package to parse the gml schemas (http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.1.0/base/).

When I parse the gmlBase.xsd schema and then save it back out, the quote characters around GeometryCollections in the BagType complex type come out converted to bad characters (See code below).

Is there something wrong with how I'm parsing or saving the xml, or is there something in the schema that is off?

Thanks,

Curtis

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
   File schemaFile = File.createTempFile("gml_", ".xsd");
   FileUtils.writeStringToFile(schemaFile, getSchema(new URL("http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.1.0/base/gmlBase.xsd")));
   System.out.println("wrote file: " + schemaFile.getAbsolutePath());
}

public static String getSchema(URL schemaURL)
{
    try
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new    StringReader(IOUtils.toString(schemaURL.openStream()))));
        Element rootElem = doc.getDocumentElement();
        rootElem.normalize();

        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();

        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        ByteArrayOutputStream xmlOutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(xmlOutStream);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        return xmlOutStream.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm suspicious of this line:

```
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(
     new StringReader(IOUtils.toString(schemaURL.openStream()))));
```

I don't know what `IOUtils.toString` does here but presumably it's assuming a particular encoding, without taking account of the XML declaration.

Why not just use:

```
Document doc = db.parse(schemaURL.openStream());
```

Likewise your `FileUtils.writeStringToFile` doesn't appear to specify a character encoding... which encoding does it use, and why encoding is in the `StreamResult`?

Comment: You're on to something.  If I change the system property "file.encoding" to "UTF-8", everything works as expected.  However, I can't figure out how to do it without setting the "file.encoding" property.  My app will be a deployed web app.  I don't have the ability to change the system properties.

Comment: @Curtis: You shouldn't be relying on any fixed encoding. Do you particularly need to get the schema as a string?

Comment: I would like to write out the schema to a file so that it can be viewed later.  However, I may need to alter some of the xml elements before I write it out, That is why I parse it with the DocumentBuilder first.  How can I do that without relying on an encoding?  The original code did not specify any encoding, and the file comes out invalid.

Comment: @Curtis: Modify it while it's in `Document` form, and then write it straight out to a stream.

Comment: I think I see what you mean now.  I use xmlOutStream.toByteArray() instead of xmlOutStream.toString() and it does maintain the encoding (without me having to specify or change any encoding setttings).  Thanks!  (and don't use Apache FileUtils, that messes it up too).

Comment: Nevermind on the Apache FileUtils comment.  it must have been because it was being converted to a string before being writen out.